# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') while running migration for the first time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

When I try to run migration it said build successful but when it starts running it ends with an error Value cannot be null. (Parameter `'connectionString'`), I don't know what I do wrong, below I have my `Startup.cs`, `appsettings.json`, and my `context.cs`

my *`Startup.cs`*:

```
    
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EPlanner.Context;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace EPlanner
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<EPlannerDBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EPannerContext")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

my *`appsettings.json`*:

```
    {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "EPlannerDBContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EPlannerContext-861fa7c2-c02e-48d5-8f51-2499b86337b2;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

My *`DbContext`*:

```
using EPlanner.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EPlanner.Context
{
    public class EPlannerDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<ApplicationViewModel> Applications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PaymentViewModel> Payments { get; set; }


        public EPlannerDBContext(DbContextOptions<EPlannerDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

          
        }
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
Add-Migration Initials
```

, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using correct connection in code

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("EPannerContext")
```

Replace the above code by one below

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("EPlannerDBContext")
```